# How can i manage10 SATA drives separately with same speed as DAS

Tags: hard-drive, sata, desktop, storage

I have 10 External USB drives attached with my desktop.

Each has its own `power` and `USB cable` + USB extension/extender.

Its looking very messy and i am thinking of opening the case and then take out internal SATA drives and put them in some enclosue box

now i have these queries

1. What enclosure i can use which can have 10 sata drives
2. How can i join the enclosure to my desktop and what will be speed of that
3. I searched internet but could not find what we call that product

I don't want to use any RAID , just plain disks attached to computer

or

If its possible i can get separate computer with all disks attached and then use that as Fileserver. But i am not sure network speed speed will same as DAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much you are willing to spend.  If you have an eSATA port, I have seen external enclosures with SATA port multipliers that handle at least 6 drives off the single eSATA port.  These are relatively affordable and will perform *much* better than USB2.  If money is no object, you want an external SAS enclosure but will need to pop for a SAS controller to go with it, and this gets expensive quick.  This can easily allow for full performance of all drives at once, compared to only 3 Gbps shared between all drives in a single eSATA-II connected enclosure with port multiplier.

Comment: can you show some photo of how does external sata enclosure look like

Comment: @user1721949, put the name in the search box at newegg.com or something and you will find a bunch.  They come in all sorts of different shapes and sizes, but the principal is simply that it's a box that holds drives, has a power supply and fan, and one or more SAS or SATA connectors.